# I have a wordpress site. There is a form in one of the pages of the portal. How could I figure out the form source

Tags: wordpress, forms

I have a Wordpress site. There is a form in one of the pages of the portal. By looking at the code ( By viewing the source in the browser ) > how could I figure out the form source ( the form source code or the plugin that was used to create the form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/form/) on WordPress sites are mediated by code in [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/).

Read the HTML code in your browser. For example, right-click on one of the form fields (perhaps the Submit button) and choose Inspect. Look at the code and try to pick out a symbol ... an `id` or `class` name or something ... that looks like it might relate to the form plugin. Then go to https://wpdirectory.net and search the source code of all the publicly published plugins for that symbol. With any luck it will identify the plugin.

This process takes some trial and error.

Or, if you have administrative access to the site, go to the Plugins page from your dashboard and look to see which plugins are active.